# Switch vs Router in development environment setup

Tags: switch, router

I am a developer and I am trying to setup a network for 10 servers. Based on the following link: https://askleo.com/whats_the_difference_between_a_hub_a_switch_and_a_router/, I understand the following points:

1. Routers have DHCP function to issue IP address to the servers connected.
2. Switch does not have DHCP function and servers connected to the switch should be assigned with static IP address.

In this case, should I buy a router or switch to setup my network? Why/what should I buy to setup my network?

Comment: Does you dev network need Internet access? Do you already have that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that there are two very different classes of device reffered to by the name "router". They share in common that they forward at the IP layer but the similarity largely ends there.

First off are the devices used by homes and small buisnesses to connect their networks to the internet. These typically connect two networks, reffered to as the "LAN side" and the "WAN side". On the WAN side there is typically a single port which may be Ethernet or it may be a port designed for a specific type of internet connection (DSL, CABLE, GPON etc). On the LAN side there is typically a built-in switch to provide multiple ports and a built-in wireless access point to provide wireless access. In addtion to the two-port router fuctionality these devices typically provide network address translation, basic firewalling and a DHCP server. Routing functionality on such devices is typically very minimal, if you are lucky they might support static routes, if you are unlucky all they will be able to do is the routing needed in the specific scenario they were designed for.

Then there are the devices used for routing in large networks. The main function of these devices is to route between many IP networks. Typically routing protols will be used to distribute routes and one of the key features of such a router is how large a routing table it can handle. Such routers may or may not have features beyond that such as firewalling, network address translation or the ability to bridge multiple ports onto the same L2 network.

Then to further complicate things there are "L3 switches". These are switches but that also have some IP routing functionality. Usually they do not support NAT.

---

> In this case, should I buy a router or switch to setup my network? Why/what should I buy to setup my network?

You don't give many details about what you need out of this network, so lets make some assumptions.

1. The servers need to be able to communicate with each other.
2. The servers need to be able to make outgoing connections to the Internet.
3. Incoming connections should be very restricted if allowed at all.
4. You have a single Ethernet port and IP address (which may or may not be behind NAT) on an existing network which you intend to use to provide internet access to your dev network.
5. It's a dev network, cost is more important than reliability.

Whatever you do I think you need to buy a switch, most home/small buisness routers only have four ports on the LAN side which is not enough for your 10 servers.

For servers static IP addressing is generally the way to go so you don't need to worrying about DHCP.

For accessing the Internet I see two options.

1. Use a home/small buisness router to provide routing/NAT/firewalling between your new network and the existing network. If you do this make sure the router you buy uses an Ethernet port on the WAN side.
2. Have one of your servers connected to both your new network and the existing network and have it provide routing/NAT/firewalling.

The second option is more flexible and saves you buying a home/small buisness router but it requires you to know what you are doing with setting up those features on your server OS of choice whereas the home/small buisness router will work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between a switch and a router, which the article fails to mention, is that switches forward at layer 2 and routers at layer 3.  When an Ethernet frame arrives at a switch it uses the destination MAC address to make it's forwarding decision.  A router uses the packet's destination IP address for forwarding.  A switch's forwarding table consists of MAC addresses and outgoing interfaces.  A router's forwarding table consists of IP subsets with next-hop IP addresses and outgoing interfaces.  Switches essentially forward traffic within a subnet, so if a device has an IP address of 192.168.1.5/24 and another device has 192.168.1.10/24 a switch can forward traffic between the two.  If the device wants to talk to a device on another subnet (i.e. 192.168.2.5/24) a router would be required.  To further complicate things L3 switches are available which can forward at L3.  Switches make forwarding decisions at line-rate using specialist ASICs, whereas routers generally use a CPU for forwarding, so they can have variable throughout depending on the current load.  L3 switches forward L3 at line-rate as the logic is implemented in ASICs.  L3 switch usually have a limited feature set compared to a full blown router as they require ASICs for each function.

Answer (score 1):

As a brief side note, Layer 3 switches can function similar to a router and provide DHCP pools same as a router would. Layer 2 switches which I am assuming is what the article is referring to based on what I read, does not have any routing capabilities. The big key difference is what 'qualeboy' stated in his response, ASICS is not available in routers making the forwarding decisions based on next hop IP addresses and other forwarding decisions using CPU interrupts. Of course with CEF involved that helps out with most of it's forwarding decisions but that is a whole different topic. Layer 3 switches will be able to FORWARD the data at wire speed and use routing capabilities, but because of the lack of CPU available it will only have limited features as a quote-on-quote router.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a switch.  Routers generally don't have enough ports, while even inexpensive switches have 12-24 ports.

If your network doesn't connect to anything else, that's all you need.  but if you also want Internet access, or you need to connect to another network, then you also need a router.  If you're connecting to the Internet, hen you also need a firewall, but some routers include this functionality.

If all you have is a switch, but you still need DHCP, you can run a DHCP server (daemon) on one of your servers.  That's actually more common than using a router.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers don't need Internet and you will only connect from server to server a switch should be fine, if all your server are in the same subnet eg 192.168.1.0/24.